# Apache: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, apache, postgresql

Apache 2.4.4 is not loading two modules.  The modules exist in the directory where it is looking.

I'm using Windows 8.1, PHP 5.4.12, and a WAMPServer installation.

> [Thu Oct 20 19:12:33.092619 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6888:tid 548] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3172
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'm:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/ext/php_pdo_pgsql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'm:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/ext/php_pgsql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
>
> [Thu Oct 20 19:12:33.319122 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3172:tid 448] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

My PHP, Apache, and PostgreSQL are all 64 bit.

I added the directory (m:\PostgreSQL\9.3\lib) that includes libpq.dll to my Path and then restarted but it didn't help.

I also tried copying libpq.dll into the Apache bin directory.

Are there any other dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding the PostgreSQL bin directory to the Path (Environmental Variable).

Answer (score 0):

for my case PHP 7.2.26 , it was under:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

on php.ini such that ;extension=pgsql becomes:

```
extension=pgsql
```